# How can I exclude pagination and sorting using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jsp, datatables, jspdf

Is there any way I can exclude pagination and sorting from my PDF? I'm using bootstrap template as well as data tables.

[image]

I am only trying to print the table.
Also is it possible to add a header to this? As well as other elements?

```js
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#example1").DataTable();
        $('#example2').DataTable({
            
          "paging": true,
          "lengthChange": false,
          "searching": false,
          "ordering": true,
          "info": true,
          "autoWidth": false         
        });
      });
      
          function demoFromHTML() {
              
        var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', 'pt', 'legal');
        // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
        // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
        source = $('#content')[0];

        // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
        // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
        // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
        // (class, of compound) at this time.
        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
        // 'inches' in this case
        pdf.fromHTML(
        source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, { // y coord
            'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },

        function (dispose) {
            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            pdf.save('Test.pdf');
        }, margins);
    }
    </script>
```

```html
                 <div class="box-body" id="content">
                 <a href="javascript:demoFromHTML()" class="btn btn-primary">Run Code</a>
                <div class="box-body" id="content">
  
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                <tr>                   
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Shift</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Trans. No.</th>
                    <th>U/Cost</th>
                    <th>Liters</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Cash Deposit</th>
                    <th>Check Deposit</th>
                    <th>Variance</th>
                    <th>Cashier</th>
                </tr>
                    </thead>                    
                    <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${SalesReport}" var="p">              
                    <tr>
                        <td>${p.date}</td>
                        <td>${p.shift}</td>
                        <td>${p.product}</td>
                        <td>${p.nooftrans}</td>
                        <td>${p.uprice}</td>
                        <td>${p.tank1liters}</td>
                        <td>${p.cashdepoamt}</td>
                        <td>${p.cashdepoamt}</td>
                        <td>${p.checkdepoamt}</td>
                        <td>${p.variance}</td>
                        <td>${p.cashier}</td>                        
                    </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>                    
                  </table>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              </div><!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: Are you talking about the little captions at the bottom? The 'showing 1 of 7' stuff?

Comment: Yes, that's it, as well as the show entries, search, previous, 1 and next.